# xcode 4.2.5 occupied a lot of memory ，start with some git process

Tags: xcode, macos

Recently my computer become quiet slow, and I checked out Activity Monitor and find xcode occupied about 1G memory. And everytime I launched xcode, there are some git process which I believe are the cause.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what OSX/Hardware versions you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating to the most recent version of XCode (5.0)